# Count number of rows between minute time intervals - Python

Tags: python, pandas, time, group-by, keyword-argument

I would like to count the number of rows with 30 minute time intervals, using the groupby function, with the 30  minute intervals counted from the first cell down column. Here is what I have:

```
    LOGINID DATE    TIME
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 08:54:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 08:57:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:01:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:19:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:26:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:41:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 10:03:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 11:35:00.000000000
    mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 11:36:00.000000000
    mickey  1/2/2018    0 days 09:54:00.000000000
    mickey  1/2/2018    0 days 10:21:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 09:00:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:20:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:14:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:51:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 11:05:00.000000000
    minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 11:24:00.000000000
    minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:20:00.000000000
    minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:25:00.000000000
    minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:39:00.000000000

This is what I want: 
LOGINID DATE    TIME    intense_cnt
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 08:54:00.000000000   4
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 08:57:00.000000000   4
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:01:00.000000000   3
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:19:00.000000000   3
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:26:00.000000000   2
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 09:41:00.000000000   2
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 10:03:00.000000000   1
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 11:35:00.000000000   2
mickey  1/1/2018    0 days 11:36:00.000000000   2
mickey  1/2/2018    0 days 09:54:00.000000000   2
mickey  1/2/2018    0 days 10:21:00.000000000   1
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 09:00:00.000000000   1
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:20:00.000000000   2
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:14:00.000000000   2
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 10:51:00.000000000   2
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 11:05:00.000000000   2
minnie  1/1/2018    0 days 11:24:00.000000000   1
minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:20:00.000000000   3
minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:25:00.000000000   3
minnie  1/2/2018    0 days 02:39:00.000000000   3
```

So for the first row, I am counting 30 minutes downwards from 8:54, which is 9:24, and that will give me a total of 4 rows.
Then for the second row, I am counting 30 minutes downwards from 8:57, which is 9:27, and that will give me a total of  4 rows
Then for the third row, I am counting 30 minutes downwards from 9:01, which is 9:31, and that will give me a total of 3 rows and so forth.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to count the 'current' date also, because in your explanation you are not consistent I think. In my code you can easily change it, by adjusting the `>` to a `>=`.

## Code

```
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

dates = [
"2018-2-1 08:54:00",
"2018-2-1 08:57:00",
"2018-2-1 09:01:00",
"2018-2-1 09:19:00",
"2018-2-1 09:26:00",
"2018-2-1 09:41:00",
"2018-2-1 10:03:00",
"2018-2-1 11:35:00",
"2018-2-1 11:36:00",
"2018-2-1 09:54:00",
"2018-2-1 10:21:00",
"2018-2-1 09:00:00",
"2018-2-1 10:20:00",
"2018-2-1 10:14:00",
"2018-2-1 10:51:00",
"2018-2-1 11:05:00",
"2018-2-1 11:24:00",
"2018-2-2 02:20:00",
"2018-2-2 02:25:00",
"2018-2-2 02:39:00"]

dates = pd.DataFrame([parser.parse(date) for date in dates])

counts = [
    int(dates[(dates > date)
        & (dates <= (date + timedelta(minutes=30)))].count())
    for date in dates[0]
]
```

## Result

```
[4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```